# Let user select a photo from a gallery

Tags: velo

After going over ANY option possible, I can't find a solution to a simple problem :

Letting a user select a photo from a large gallery and save it to collection.
Like an image picker, you pick an image from a gallery and the window is closed.

1. No photo selection option on "`user input`" menu.
2. No way to connect any gallery including Wix Gallery to a data set as `INPUT`.
3. 3rd apps let you do that but it's being saved in their own servers, and its limited to just a few photos, not to a large set

We basically have more than 100 photos in an album that a user should be able to somehow pick.

Another option is to open some kind of window with Pinterest stream and collect the URL of a selection, which also seems impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in image picker, but you can roll your own with a bit of code.

Here's a bit of code that should get you started in the right direction:

```
import wixData from 'wix-data';
import wixUsers from 'wix-users';

$w.onReady(function () {
  $w('#gallery').clickAction = "none";

  $w("#gallery").onItemClicked( (event) => {
    let imageSrc = event.item.src; 

    let toInsert = {
      "user": wixUsers.currentUser.id,
      "image": imageSrc
    }

    wixData.insert("SelectedImages", toInsert)
      .then( () => {
        $w('#gallery').hide("fold");
      } );
  } );
} );
```

This code assumes you have a collection where you want to store "selected" images. That collection has at least two fields that have the following keys: user and image.

When an image in the gallery is clicked an event handler gets the src of the image and inserts it into the collection along with the current user's ID. Then the gallery is hidden.

All of the above can be customized to fit your specific situation, but this should give you an idea of what can be done.